# How to debug UWP xaml bindings?

Tags: c#, xaml, debugging, uwp

I have a `DataGrid` that is binded to an `ObservableCollection` in my universal windows platform app.

The datagrid is not shown up when page is loaded. I have another datagrid in the same page that is almost the same but is binded to another collection almost the same as the first one(which has binding problems).

Is there any way to debug the `XAML` file ?

Sample Code:

```
<GridView Name="HourGridView" Grid.Row="4" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ForeCastsByDates}" 
          Foreground="Chartreuse" >

    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ForeCast">
                         .......
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

</GridView>
```

The collection which is not binded:

```
private ObservableCollection<ForeCast> ForeCastsByDates;
```

The collection that binded well:

```
private ObservableCollection<ForeCast> ForeCasts;
```

The ForeCastsByDates is a part of ForeCasts:

```
ForeCastsByDates = new ObservableCollection<ForeCast>( ForeCasts.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.First()));
```

Comment: Share sample code

Comment: @VinothRajendran Edited my post with sample code

Comment: Is `ForeCastsByDates` notifying on changes on the property (not on the items)? If not, either make `set`-operations on `ForeCastsByDates` emit a notification, or set the collection once in ctor and use `.Clear` and `.Add` for future adaptions.

Comment: `ForeCastsByDates` is set only once in the constructor. Can you give some example for the `.Clear` and `.Add`?

Comment: @axcelenator as the field is not declared as `readonly`, that very information was missing for me :) thanks for the clarification. Could you, just for the sake of clarity, bind the `Count`-property of the `ForeCastsByDates`-collection to a `TextBlock`'s `Text`-property?

Comment: When you run your application with the Visual Studio debugger attached you will see Binding Errors displayed in the Output window.

Comment: Your lists are  fields, not properties. See @MartinZikmund's answer.  That should still work but do make them `readonly` to verify you don't have incorrect later assignments.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, it seems that you are actually trying to bind to a class **field** not a **property**.

Data binding requires properties to work properly. To achieve that, you will have to make a `private` backing field and a `public` property that can then be accessed with data binding.

```
private ObservableCollection<ForeCast> _foreCastsByDates;
public ObservableCollection<ForeCast> ForeCastsByDates
{
   get
   {
      return _foreCastsByDates;
   }
   set 
   {
      _foreCastsByDates = value;
      //notify about changes
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

You may have noticed the property uses a `OnPropertyChanged()` method in the setter. To actually notify the user interface about changes of the property, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `Page`:

```
public partial MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // your code...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));            
    }
}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged` method fires the `PropertyChanged` event which notifies the listeners that a property has changed. In this case we need to notify about the changes to the `ForeCastsByDates` property. Using the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` used next to the `OnPropertyChanged` method parameter, the parameter is automatically set to the name of the caller (in this case the `ForeCastsByDates` property.

Finally, the `{x:Bind}` syntax defaults to `OneTime` mode, which means it is updated only once and **does not** listen to property changed. To ensure all later updates to the property are reflected, use

```
{x:Bind ForecastsByDates, Mode=OneWay}
```

Important thing to mention is that you have to make changes to the `ForecastsByDates` property itself to notify the UI (the property setter has to be executed to call the `OnPropertyChanged` method). If you do just `_foreCastsByDates = something`, the field will change, but the UI will not know about it and the change will not be reflected.

Comment: No, x:Bind can bind to fields. And will update when you arrange the RaisePropertyChanged in another way. Not a good style, obviously.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that :-O